# How can I redirect to an absolute path with react-router v4?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I have a huge Django web app, with one of it's modules (a 'dashboard') written with node and react. User login is handled by a Django module.

The user should be logged into the main app in order to access the react dashboard, and this works partially - the code gets the user session from the browser and only renders stuff if there is one.

I would like now to redirect the user to the main app login page if there is no session, but I don't know how to do it with my current structure (and this bloody v4 router).

I am using a basename in the BrowserRouter component to use routes relative to the dashboard path in the django app.

This is what I came up with for the JSX for app.jsx:

```
<BrowserRouter basename='/en/dashboard'>
    {this.state.isAuthenticated ? (
        <Paper zDepth={0} style={{ height: '100%', backgroundColor: grey900 }}>
            <div style={{height: '100%'}}>
                <Header />
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact={true} path='/' component={FirstSection}/>
                    <Route path='/first' component={FirstSection}/>
                    <Route path='/second' component={SecondSection}/>
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </Paper>
    ) : (
        <Redirect to="/en/login"/>
    )}
</BrowserRouter>
```

However, it actually redirects to `en/dashboard/en/login`. I believe I could remove the 'basename' property from the BrowserRouter and add it to each subsequent Route, but if this module eventually grows bigger, it would make routing harder. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't possible. If you're using a basename it will be added to base of every path before the href is created. This happens in the `history` module in `createBrowserHistory` in the `push` and `replace` methods which use the following function:

```
var createHref = function createHref(location) {
    return basename + (0, _PathUtils.createPath)(location);
};
```

uses either `push` or `replace` method.

You can find the following block of code in the `Redirect.prototype.perform` method:

```
if (push) {
  history.push(to);
} else {
  history.replace(to);
}
```

The above can be found in `Redirect.js` in the `react-router` module which is what the `react-router-dom` module imports and then exports.

To do what you're trying to do I would make the `basename` a const and added it to the front of your path in each of your routes.

It's unfortunate there is not an `ignoreBasename` option for a `<Route />` or `<Redirect />`, though it is implementable.

Comment: On a side note, I was able to implement an ignoreBasename option with some patching to `history/createBrowserHistory.js` and `react-router/Redirect.js`. This has me interested so I'm considering making a feature and requesting the addition into a later version.

Comment: Any news? That option would be very useful.

Comment: I'm sorry but I decided against pursuing this further. I was doing this for v4 of React-Router, `browserRouter`, which instantiates the history module on line #19. To avoid the warning produced by line #77 of `createBrowserHistory.js` you would need to add a flag to createBrowserHistory.js, include it in browserRouter, and then implement the `ignoreBasename` feature, which isn't hard, but you would need to replicate the changes across the different router types, and it affects multiple libraries. I don't feel the problem is prevalent enough to warrant the changes.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in Kyle's answer, there is no way to have  to use absolute urls or to ignore the basename; however, if you want or "need" to run the redirection from the render method of your component you can create your own ultra-light "absolute redirect" component, here's mine:

```
import React from 'react'

class AbsoluteRedirect extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        window.location = this.props.to
    }

    render(){
        return null
    }

}

export default AbsoluteRedirect
```

And then use it other components with a condition so it only gets mounted when your validation is true.

```
render(){ 

    if( shouldRedirect )
        return <AbsoluteRedirect to={ anotherWebsiteURL } />

    ...

}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without react router:

```
window.location.pathname = '/en/login';
```

Navigating away to a different site is using:

```
window.location.href = 'https://stackoverflow.com';
```