# Absolute path redirect in React

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a bit.ly clone and I would like to redirect to an exact URL.

Unfortunately if I use window.location.replace(str) in some cases it believes I would like to redirect to a relative URL. For example str = "google.com".

I'm wondering if there is a way to force an absolute path redirect that I am missing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I redirect to an absolute path with react-router v4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45197295/how-can-i-redirect-to-an-absolute-path-with-react-router-v4)

Comment: Not a duplicate - I am not using a basename in this case, and it appears that is the issue in the question you linked.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with React

Answer (score 0):

Use a URL with a schema. `google.com` is a relative URL, like `image.jpg`.

```js
location.replace('google.com');
```

```js
location.replace('http://stackoverflow.com');
```

Comment: This doesn't work because in some cases the user does not specify whether to use https:// or http:// and I don't want to make the assumption for them. Instead, I'd like the equivalent behavior of typing 'google.com' into the address bar.

Comment: The equivalent of typing `google.com` into the address bar is `http://google.com` (which will then redirect to https)

Comment: This is not always the case though. Perhaps for Google it is, but for this to work you have to explicitly configure a rule with your web server and not everyone has/wants to.

Comment: It is always the case. Browsers never assume `https`. Unless using an extension that changes this of course...

Answer (score 0):

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
```

Try importing withRouter and wrap the component with it.

```
export default (withRouter(MyComponent))
```

Now, you can use

```
this.props.history.replace('// your link');
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me - causes a maximum update depth exceeded error.

Comment: you need to make a function and call whenever you want to navigate to that url.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it does not work still though as it still navigates to a relative URL